# Is there any way to convert the Reponse JSON to Pact body format?

Tags: pact

While generating Contract , we need to enter response JSON attributes inside the Pact body. The attributes list in some Response JSON are of 1000+, in that case Manually entering details to Pact body is not Possible.

is there any tool which can convert the Response JSON to Pact body format ? is there any other solution ?

Comment: What do you mean "pact body format"? Which language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible ,to convert the Java Object into JSON with Jackson Library:

```
ObjectMapper obm = new ObjectMapper(); 
String ActualJson = obm.writeValueAsString("Object obj").
```